# How to parallelize Spark loading operation for Elasticsearch?

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, elasticsearch

I have a three node ***Spark*** cluster (8 cores and 16GB RAM each) in standalone mode. I am using ***Elasticsearch-hadoop*** connector to read an ES index. The index is really huge with over 100M documents and has 5 shards and 2 replications. When I create a dataframe using Spark, I want this load operation to be parallelized but I see that it is handled only in driver and not on the executors. This single operation alone takes over 8 hours to load. How can I optimize this and let all the worker nodes to load the data in parallel?

I submit the job using 16 executors each with 1 core and 2GB memory and driver with 4GB memory.

```
df = sqlContext.read.format("org.elasticsearch.spark.sql").option("es.nodes", es_ip).load(es_index)
df.coalesce(16).write.option("compression","gzip").parquet(pq_filename)
```

After loading this, I convert this into Parquet and save it in HDFS.